# How to match bare urls with regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, url

```
$bits = preg_split('#((?:https?|ftp)://[^\s\'"<>()]+)#S', $token->data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Say,I'm trying to match urls that need to be linkified.The above is too permissive.

I want to only match simple urls like `http://google.com`, but not `<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>`, or `<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>`

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do, eventually?

Comment: I'm trying to linkify urls,wrap it with `<a href=xxx></a>` **only when necessary**.

Comment: I thought so. This question has been asked here a couple of dozen times. Please [consider searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=), one of the answers might just do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're trying to parse HTML using regular expressions.  [You might want to rethink that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: how is matching a url in a string parsing html?

Comment: You're matching the URL within an HTML context.  Load the HTML into a DOMDocument and then test each text node against your pattern.

Comment: @wamp: If you're specifically trying to avoid a greedy algorithm that eats HTML tags, that must mean you're in a position (at least sometimes) where your link will be embedded in HTML.  And that way lies madness.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
function validUrl($url){
        $return=FALSE;
        $matches=FALSE;
        $regex='#(^';                  #match[1]
        $regex.='((https?|ftps?)+://)?'; #Scheme match[2]
        $regex.='(([0-9a-z-]+\.)+'; #Domain match[5] complete match[4]
        $regex.='([a-z]{2,3}|aero|coop|jobs|mobi|museum|name|travel))'; #TLD match[6]
        $regex.='(:[0-9]{1,5})?'; #Port match[7]
        $regex.='(\/[^ ]*)?'; #Query match[8]
        $regex.='$)#i';
        if( preg_match($regex,$url,$matches) ){
            $return=$matches[0]; $domain=$matches[4];
            if(!gethostbyname($domain)){ 
                $return = FALSE;
            }
        }
        if($return==FALSE){
            return FALSE;
        }
        else{
            return $matches;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And how does a more complex regex help in this case? Read the question again.

Comment: And in any case, trying to enumerate “valid” TLDs is an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 0):

RE

```
http:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]*
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://google.com
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**More effective RE**

```
[hf]t{1,2}p:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]*
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ftp://article-stack.com
            [1] => http://google.com
        )
)
```